# Why provide an argument for custom functions and use it in Javascript/ NPM modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am new to Javascript.
I have just got running with npm, node.js, etc.

Now, I have come across two popular packages: [mkdirp](https://github.com/substack/node-mkdirp) and [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob)
which allow for some very basic and useful functionality. In their basic version, both `mkdirp` and `glob` allow the user to provide a custom function when being called. And I have found a repo that makes use of both `mkdirp` and `glob` to define a cascade of nested function calls along roughly the following lines:

```
  mkdirp('some_path', (err) => { // first nesting
    if (!err) {
      glob(
        'some_glob_exp',
        (err, files) => { // another nesting
          if (!err) {
            // transform file
            files.map(do_something);
          };
        };
      );
    };
  })
```

My question:
What is the point of providing this functionality in `mkdirp` and `glob` and making use of it when I could do without (i.e. create the directory, then create files object, then manipulate files in files object) and possibly write more readable code? Is it good practice to nest functions like the above? Is the primary motivation for this a functional programming paradigm? error handling? efficiency? avoiding to explicitly create objects?

Comment: There's a long history of functions that take callbacks to other functions. You've got many broad questions in your question that are unlikely to be answerable in a single answer. Note that `mkdirp` and `glob` are likely asynchronous, so you can't just "create the directory, then create files object", since you won't know when the creation of the directory is complete.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you recommend deleting the question in this case? In case you can recommend any general/ broad reading on this, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ususally for efficiency. The term here is asynchronous I/O. The idea is that the thread can work on other things until the input/output operation is complete and come back to your callback later.

That nesting is indeed a little ugly, that's why async/await/promises were introduced.

You could have a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) - they have a really good description of how to use await.

Comment: This is a good answer. I wasn't aware of the asynchronous nature of many Javascript functions and functionality provided by npm packages. In my concrete example, there were dependencies between the code blocks, first create directory, then create files in this directory, etc. and it is crucial to execute these sequentially (synchronously), but I still find the use of callbacks  and resulting callback hell in the code snippet above not ideal, looking into alternatives to make the code nicer.